# How to check memory performance using Instruments and how to improve it?

Tags: performance, macos, memory, instruments

I have to check memory performance of my application, I have solved Leaks now I want to improve the performance of memory.

So, please tell me the process how can I fix and improve the memory performance.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by the vague term "memory performance". I would suggest first using Shark to look at cache misses and/or DRAM bandwidth - that should help you to focus on any parts of your code where memory accesses may be a limiting factor.

Comment: Actually after checking all leaks and object allocations in iphone application, next step is Activity Monitor in Xcode for checking performance. I don't no how to go with Activity Monitor.

Comment: OK - you should probably put an `iPhone` tag on your question, because it currently reads like a Mac OS X programming question.

Comment: @PaulR, where's Shark? Is it still included with Xcode 4.0.2 and iOS SDK 4.3?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: unfortunately with the move to Xcode 4 Apple seems to have deprecated Shark in favour of Instruments. There's a Time Profile module and various other related modules in Instruments which you can use instead of Shark - it's not as good but it should at least give you some useful information.